# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.when executing two merge queries

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to execute the query shown here, but I get an error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

I don't understand where my mistake is... when I'm taking only count it is executing but when taking sum showing error

```
select
    (select count(1) as lead_count, sum(net_premium)  
     from g_hdfclms 
     where qc_date > '2019-12-12'  
     group by net_premium)
    +
    (select count(1) as lead_count, sum(net_premium) 
     from g_proposal_m  
     where field1 > '2019-12-12' 
     group by net_premium)
```

in image im getting two count but i want to merge this count as well as there sum

[image]

Comment: This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to acheive?

Comment: You **cannot** have two select's that both return **two values** (two columns) and then use a `+` operator to "combine" them - what exactly is your expectation anyway, what is this `+` supposed to do in your opinion?? The `+` operator can work only on **single** int's, strings, etc. - but **not** on result sets with multiple columns

Comment: i want to show total count and total sum of premium in one select query

Comment: You probably want to union the two sub queries and then do count and sum on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you want to cross join both queries and compute two additions in the `select` clause:

```
select 
    t1.lead_count + t2.lead_count lead_count,
    t1.sum_net_premium + t2.sum_net_premium sum_net_premium
from    
    (
        select count(*) as lead_count, sum(net_premium)  sum_net_premium
        from g_hdfclms 
        where qc_date > '2019-12-12'  
        group by net_premium
    ) t1
    cross join (
        select count(*) as lead_count, sum(net_premium) sum_net_premium
        from g_proposal_m  
        where field1 > '2019-12-12' 
        group by net_premium
    ) t2
```

Comment: thank you for reply but i want to show total count and total sum not individual

Comment: @Atul: as far as I understand your comment, this is what the query does. Please run it and see the results. If this is not what you expect, please update your question to show the result that you do expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here I get desire out out

```
select 'total_lead' as total_lead,(select  count(lead_id_lms) from g_hdfclms  where qc_date > '2019-12-12') +(select  count(lead_id_lms) from g_proposal_m  where field1 > '2019-12-12') as total_count
union
select 'total_premium' as total_lead, (select  sum(net_premium) from g_hdfclms where qc_date > '2019-12-12'  )+(select  sum(net_premium) from g_proposal_m where field1 > '2019-12-12')  as total_count
```

[image]